# Efficiently applying transition to state matrix given transition matrix

Tags: python, numpy, transition, numba

I'm looking to apply a state change to a large categorical matrix (M) with k categories where I know the transition probabilities of every category to each other category in k (T)

Essentially I want to be able to efficiently take each element in M, simulate a state change given the probabilities in T, and replace the element with the calculated change.

I've tried a few solutions :

- brute force nested for loops with indexing (much much too long)
- numba assisted nested for loops (~500ms which is too long for my purposes)
- precalculated draws for each category and replacement (~400ms)

```py
import numpy as np


def categorical_transition(mat, t_mat, k=4):

    transformed_mat = mat.copy()
    cat_counts = np.bincount(mat.reshape(-1,))

    for i in range(k):
        rand_vec = np.random.multinomial(1, t_mat[i], cat_counts[i])

        choice = np.where(rand_vec)[1]

        transformed_mat[mat == i] = choice

    return transformed_mat


# load data
mat = np.random.choice(4, (16000, 256))
t_mat = np.random.random((4, 4))

# normalize transition matrix
for i in range(t_mat.shape[0]):
    t_mat[i] = t_mat[i] / t_mat[i].sum()

transformed_mat = categorical_transition(mat, t_mat)
```

This method works, but it is slow and I would appreciate any advice on more efficient ways to implement it

Comment: do you need to copy the matrix? Can you not just modify the original one? Copying a large object often takes a good chunk of time...

Comment: yes unfortunately. Perhaps not wrapped in the function but I am planning on doing many transitions from an original matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Always provide all implementations you tried so far**

I tried for example a simple implementation as decribed [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#To_simulate_from_a_multinomial_distribution) It should be around 20-80 times faster than your solution, depending on how many cores you have available.

**Implementation**

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True)  
def categorical_transition_nb(mat_in, t_mat):
    mat=np.reshape(mat_in,-1)
    transformed_mat = np.empty_like(mat)
    for i in nb.prange(mat.shape[0]):
        rand_number=np.random.rand()
        probabilities=t_mat[mat[i],:]
        if rand_number<probabilities[0]:
            transformed_mat[i]=0
        else:
            for j in range(1,probabilities.shape[0]):
                if rand_number>=probabilities[j-1] and rand_number<probabilities[j]:
                    transformed_mat[i]=j

    return transformed_mat.reshape(mat_in.shape)
```

**Timings**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

# load data
mat = np.random.choice(4, (16_000,256))
t_mat = np.random.random((4, 4))

# normalize transition matrix
for i in range(t_mat.shape[0]):
    t_mat[i] = t_mat[i] / t_mat[i].sum()

t_mat_2=np.cumsum(t_mat,axis=1)
%timeit transformed_mat_2 = categorical_transition_nb(mat, t_mat_2)
21.7 ms ± 1.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that gives me a 5-fold speedup on the example

```
import numpy as np

def categorical_transition(mat, t_mat, k=4):

    transformed_mat = mat.copy()
    cat_counts = np.bincount(mat.reshape(-1,))

    for i in range(k):
        rand_vec = np.random.multinomial(1, t_mat[i], cat_counts[i])

        choice = np.where(rand_vec)[1]

        transformed_mat[mat == i] = choice

    return transformed_mat

def pp(mat,t_mat):
    ps = t_mat.cumsum(1)
    ps /= ps[:,-1:]
    return (np.random.random(mat.shape+(1,))<ps[mat]).argmax(-1)


# load data
mat = np.random.choice(4, (16000, 256))
t_mat = np.random.random((4, 4))

# normalize transition matrix
for i in range(t_mat.shape[0]):
    t_mat[i] = t_mat[i] / t_mat[i].sum()

transformed_mat = categorical_transition(mat, t_mat)
transformed_mat_pp = pp(mat, t_mat)

# check correctness
from pprint import pprint
np.set_printoptions(3)

cnts = np.bincount(mat.ravel())
pprint([[np.bincount(tm[mat==i])/cnts[i] for tm in (transformed_mat,transformed_mat_pp)] + [t_mat[i]] for i in range(4)])

from timeit import timeit

print('OP',timeit(lambda:categorical_transition(mat, t_mat),number=10)*100,'ms')
print('pp',timeit(lambda:pp(mat, t_mat),number=10)*100,'ms')
```

Sample run:

```
[[array([0.186, 0.1  , 0.078, 0.637]),
  array([0.186, 0.099, 0.078, 0.637]),
  array([0.186, 0.099, 0.078, 0.637])],
 [array([0.303, 0.517, 0.088, 0.092]),
  array([0.303, 0.517, 0.089, 0.092]),
  array([0.303, 0.517, 0.088, 0.092])],
 [array([0.319, 0.27 , 0.329, 0.082]),
  array([0.319, 0.271, 0.328, 0.083]),
  array([0.318, 0.27 , 0.329, 0.082])],
 [array([0.408, 0.106, 0.264, 0.222]),
  array([0.409, 0.107, 0.263, 0.221]),
  array([0.408, 0.107, 0.264, 0.221])]]
OP 872.7993675973266 ms
pp 170.54899749346077 ms
```